# Is it possible to ripping a CD via another computer?

Tags: command-line, networking, windows, windows-xp, cd-ripping

I have multiple computer on my local network. Some of it use Windows OS. On one of Windows system, it had one CD drive. I'm also have Ubuntu system on another computer.

This's the scheme:

```
+---------+      +-------+      +--------+
| Windows |------|  LAN  |------| Ubuntu |
+---------+      +-------+      +--------+
     |                              ^
     V                              |
 +--------+                     +---------+
 | CD-ROM |                     | It's me |
 +--------+                     +---------+
```

Is it possible to ripping a CD from Ubuntu via another Windows computer? By the way, I have samba, TightVNC, and telnet to connect to Windows. But I prefer command line interface.

Comment: it is. 1) set cd drive to "share on network; 2) mount drive via samba (use `smbclient` for command line access) | alternatively try a cifs-mount

Comment: Basically you are asking if you can rip a cd-rom on a WINDOWS system from command line. Can Windows do that? We can not answer that: problems/questions about the left hand side of the ascii art is off topic ;)  On Ubuntu I would use "ssh" to connect and "dd" to rip the CD and "scp" to copy the file over to the machine you use.

Comment: I mean, can I ripping CD from Ubuntu via Windows machine which Ubuntu as RIPPING machine and WINDOWS as CD-DRIVE? Directly access via samba share not work, because it's CD-Audio.  Dot cda-files in CD drive is only presentation file which created by Windows for each track. That's the problem.

Comment: Here's my full command: `sudo mount -o "username=$USER,password=${my-password},uid=${UID},gid=${GROUPS},dir_mode=0700,file_mode=0700,nounix" -t "cifs" "//WINDOWS/cd-rom" "/mnt"`

Comment: @Fiximan: I'm sorry your comment accidentally deleted. :D

Comment: It was on purpose - I mixed up two mount protocols. My bad. How does that mount turn out? Next step would be trying "network block devices" for the share.

Comment: It show TrackXX.cda. I tried play it on `gnome-mplayer` show error: `(gnome-mplayer:17833): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 700 was not found when attempting to remove it`. When I tried `vlc`: `[0x7f6988c01828] es demux error: cannot peek`. It's like something doesn't exist there. Once again, I'm so sorry. :D

Answer (score 2):

**Background** on '*ripping*'

You need sophisticated control of the CD-drive, to facilitate extracting the music tracks. This is not an exact science, and works best (for me) using **Rubyripper** (on Linux). Even then it uses multiple attempts, and adjusts other low-level parameters.

Remotely mounting the CD-drive will read CD-ROM 'data', and may play ***some really old CDs*** (or tracks) but ***definitely*** not all.

---

*You need to look for a solution (and remote access this from Linux) based on (Windows-based) software running on the Windows machine.* (**That should be asked on another forum.**)

**I strongly suggest *borrowing* the CD-drive, OR just installing Linux (alongside Windows) on the machine with the CD-drive.**

---

PS. Stop using **Windows XP**

Comment: So, your method basically just ripping directly from (inner or console or terminal) machine. Not remote ripping? _Off the topic: I still like Windows XP than all newest Windows and I prefer Ubuntu than them all. :P_

Comment: @bayuah: As you're a reputation 11 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby But, it's not, yet. I still wait another answer which, maybe, give me how to _remote ripping_, not just ask another machine to ripping. :)

Comment: @bayuah ***Answer clarified with bold and italics***  From Ubuntu to Ubuntu: *maybe.  From Ubuntu to Windows XP???* Nah! Not going to happen! 

P.S. Upgrade the Windows XP to Lubuntu!

Comment: David: I wish I could upvote twice!  Once for the excellent answer and once for the XP comment!  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby Hey. I use both (Windows XP and **Lubuntu**).